# How do I get path of the Directory inside my WinForm app project

Tags: vb.net, directory, projects-and-solutions, startup

I have a directory named reports inside my winform project in .net. My project name is AccountingReports and inside that Directory reports exists. So i need the way to access this path via code. In Asp.net we use Request.PhysicalApplicationPath property. So is there any method or property exists that will give me the root of my project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

[`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(VS.71).aspx)

> Gets the current working directory of the application.

You can then append "Reports" to that using the following:

[`Path.Combine(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

```
Dim reportsFolder As String
reportsFolder = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Reports")
```

Comment: that still gave me \bin\debug [current working directory of executable], so i need to put the reports inside the debug directory to test my application...& further the installed location will be AppInstallDir/Reports/ to make it work... am i right?
no other approach coming in mind..

Comment: @Amit - yes, unless you put the location into the app.config directory and read it from there.

Comment: Then in this case after deployment user need to update the app.config file each and every time he moves Reports directory.

Comment: @Amit - unless you provide a settings dialog option for them to update it.

Answer (score 7):

```vb
Dim path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
'replace \bin\Debug\ the part of the path you dont want  with part you do want
Dim path1 As String = path.Replace("\bin\Debug\", "\htmlFiles\")
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me while developing a VSTO add-in. Shame on everyone else for not catching this.

Answer (score 1):

When running in the IDE vs. Installed I have used:

If `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` - true if installed, false IDE

installed - `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory`

IDE - `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath`

Comment: still the same My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath = \bin\debug

Comment: anyways i need to do some parsing over the string or copy paste it to executable dir..anyways thanks for kind support..

Comment: It is always amusing to get downvotes on a six year old post with no explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Well. A lil' bit late maybe, but I just had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
    Dim Path As String() = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory.ToString.Split(New Char() {"\"c})
    For i = 0 To Path.Count - 3
        PathLb.Text = PathLb.Text & "\" & Path(i)
    Next i
    PathLb.Text = PathLb.Text.Remove(0, 1)
```

With this the path is contained on 'PathLb'.

Hope its useful to anyone.